# Solr - how do I index barcode

Tags: solr, solr4

I have a documnet that contains the following data

```
car {
    id:     guid
    name:   string
    sku:   list<barcode>
}
```

Now, 
The barcodes dont have a pattern. It can be either one of the follwings:

```
ABCD-EF34GD-JOHN
ABCD-C08-YUVF
```

I want to index my documents so that search for
    1. ABCD will return both.
    2. AB will return both.
    3. JO - will return ABCD-EF34GD-JOHN but not car with name john.
    4. If the ID (which is indexed) contains "ABCD", i dont want the document to be returned (the user doesn't see it)

so far I have defined car and sku as text_en.
But I dont get bulletes no 2 and 3.
IS there a better way to define sku attribute.

My Query is

```
 http://....:8983/solr/vault/select?q=ABCD&qf=Name+SKU&defType=edismax
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can we see the query you are trying to run there? a simple text field is not enough fot the type of results you want

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/vault/select?q=ABCD&qf=Name+SKU&defType=edismax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do here is actually a wildcard search on the tokens separated by the dash ("-").

An easy (but slow in performance) way is to add a star (*) at the end of your word in the query, like this:

```
http://....:8983/solr/vault/select?q=AB*&qf=Name+SKU&defType=edismax
```

Another option is to change the field type that you use to index and implement an NGram algoritm. If you use this filter in your field you will create a toklen for each combination of letters in the word you are indexing. For example: ABCD => AB, ABC, ABCD
So it will find what you are looking for and the search will be very fast, but the index will be very big and the indexation time will also increase notably.

You can find more info here:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory

Comment: This is a great answer but wouldnt JO* return both JOHN in Name and John in SKU?

Comment: No I think that specific query search in the default field. So it depend on wich one is your default field. Try this otherwise: q=SKU:AB*

Comment: No it did not. field is declared as text_en in the schema, btw.

Comment: Did you try the NGram solution?